# Save audio stream into file with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsfilemanager, cfnetwork

I've some trouble with audio streaming using MPMoviePlayerController.
I want to know if it's possible to save the data streaming info to a file while MPMoviePlayer is playing that file.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try to use background processing

Answer (score 1):

According to apple (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html) for streaming audio you connect to a network stream using CFNetwork interfaces from CoreFoundation, then parse the network packets into audio packets using Audio File Stream Service (AudioToolbox/AudioFileStream.h) and then play the audio packets using Audio Queue Services (AudioToolbox/AudioQueue.h) ….

Now my idea is that if we can find some way to write the audio packets to the file in between sending the packets to the audio queue then we can save the audio stream while playing them…

Its just an idea that needs implementation and don't know weather it will work for video stream or not.